# Snowpark: replace missing values by another column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to count the total number of missing values in a column, and replace the missing values of one column with the value from another column in snowpark python?

In pandas, I have something like this:

```
df["NULL_CHECK"] = np.select([

        df["col1"].isna() & df["col2"].notna(),                        
        df["col1"].isna() & df["col2"].isna() & df["col3"].notna()],
        [1,2],
        default=0 
        )
 df.loc[df["NULL_CHECK"] == 1, "col1"] = df["col2"]
 df.loc[df["NULL_CHECK"] == 2, "col1"] = df["col3"]
```

Is it possible to achieve similar to this using snowpark python functions?

Thank you!

Not sure, if something like this is correct:

```
snowpark_df = snowpark_df.with_column("col1",F.call_builtin("ifnull", F.col("col1"), F.col("col2")))
```

Comment: Hi - so what happened when you tried the solution that you came up with? What issues did you have?

Comment: It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Takes *col1*, checks if *col1* is null, and if certain values are null, they are replaced with the corresponding values of *col2*

`snowpark_df = snowpark_df.with_column("col1",F.call_builtin("ifnull", F.col("col1"), F.col("col2")))`.